Singularity build crashes because of pip memory usage
I am currently trying to build quite a simple .sif image from a .def file with singularity 4.1.3.
The problem is that whatever settings I try to use for pip install, I always fail the build due to:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
I have tried setting the TMPDIR variable, tried using the pip --no-cache-dir options but nothing does change.
I am using Fedora 39 and I have 8GB of RAM. Back when I was using Ubuntu I have never experienced anything like this and i was building perhaps heavier images.
The .def file for singularity is the following:
Bootstrap: library
From: ubuntu:20.04

%post
  export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
  apt-get -qq -y update

  apt-get -qq -y install apt-utils > /dev/null

  apt-get -qq -y install --no-install-recommends \
      python3 \
      python3-tk \
      python3-pip \
      python3-distutils \
      python3-setuptools \

  pip3 install -q langchain faiss-cpu torch sentence_transformers```

During building of the image I can see (through htop) that as soon as the build enters the "pip install" section the RAM usage steadily increases up to 5.9GB/6.7GB, at this time the build gets killed with the error:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

FATAL:   While performing build: while running engine: exit status 1

Full output of the command is:
WARNING: 'nodev' mount option set on /tmp, it could be a source of failure during build process
INFO:    Starting build...
INFO:    Using cached image
INFO:    Verifying bootstrap image /root/.singularity/cache/library/sha256.cfb23cc09dd3b4570110dd6f13886fe95cc31ef2d81f7abab6796751f5700fa0
INFO:    Running post scriptlet
+ export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
+ apt-get -qq -y update
+ apt-get -qq -y install apt-utils
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
+ apt-get -qq -y install --no-install-recommends python3 python3-tk python3-pip python3-distutils python3-setuptools
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libssl1.1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 4162 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.22_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.22) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython3.8-minimal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libexpat1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libexpat1_2.2.9-1ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libexpat1:amd64 (2.2.9-1ubuntu0.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3.8-minimal.
Preparing to unpack .../python3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.8-minimal (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9) ...
Setting up libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.22) ...
Setting up libpython3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9) ...
Setting up libexpat1:amd64 (2.2.9-1ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up python3.8-minimal (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-minimal.
(Reading database ... 4463 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-python3-minimal_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-minimal (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mime-support.
Preparing to unpack .../1-mime-support_3.64ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmpdec2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../2-libmpdec2_2.4.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmpdec2:amd64 (2.4.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package readline-common.
Preparing to unpack .../3-readline-common_8.0-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking readline-common (8.0-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreadline8:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libreadline8_8.0-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreadline8:amd64 (8.0-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsqlite3-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libsqlite3-0_3.31.1-4ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.31.1-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../6-libpython3.8-stdlib_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3.8.
Preparing to unpack .../7-python3.8_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.8 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython3-stdlib:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../8-libpython3-stdlib_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3-stdlib:amd64 (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up python3-minimal (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3.
(Reading database ... 4893 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-python3_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3 (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openssl.
Preparing to unpack .../01-openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.22_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openssl (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.22) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ca-certificates.
Preparing to unpack .../02-ca-certificates_20230311ubuntu0.20.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking ca-certificates (20230311ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libbsd0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libbsd0_0.10.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libbsd0:amd64 (0.10.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-pkg-resources.
Preparing to unpack .../04-python3-pkg-resources_45.2.0-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pkg-resources (45.2.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tzdata.
Preparing to unpack .../05-tzdata_2024a-0ubuntu0.20.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking tzdata (2024a-0ubuntu0.20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ucf.
Preparing to unpack .../06-ucf_3.0038+nmu1_all.deb ...
Moving old data out of the way
Unpacking ucf (3.0038+nmu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpng16-16:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libpng16-16_1.6.37-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpng16-16:amd64 (1.6.37-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxau6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libxau6_1%3a1.0.9-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxau6:amd64 (1:1.0.9-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxdmcp6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libxdmcp6_1%3a1.1.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxdmcp6:amd64 (1:1.1.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxcb1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libxcb1_1.14-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb1:amd64 (1.14-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-data.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libx11-data_2%3a1.6.9-2ubuntu1.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking libx11-data (2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libx11-6_2%3a1.6.9-2ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxext6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libxext6_2%3a1.3.4-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxext6:amd64 (2:1.3.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtcl8.6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libtcl8.6_8.6.10+dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtcl8.6:amd64 (8.6.10+dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfreetype6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libfreetype6_2.10.1-2ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfreetype6:amd64 (2.10.1-2ubuntu0.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fonts-dejavu-core.
Preparing to unpack .../16-fonts-dejavu-core_2.37-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-dejavu-core (2.37-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fontconfig-config.
Preparing to unpack .../17-fontconfig-config_2.13.1-2ubuntu3_all.deb ...
Unpacking fontconfig-config (2.13.1-2ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfontconfig1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../18-libfontconfig1_2.13.1-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfontconfig1:amd64 (2.13.1-2ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxrender1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../19-libxrender1_1%3a0.9.10-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxrender1:amd64 (1:0.9.10-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxft2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../20-libxft2_2.3.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxft2:amd64 (2.3.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package x11-common.
Preparing to unpack .../21-x11-common_1%3a7.7+19ubuntu14_all.deb ...
dpkg-query: no packages found matching nux-tools
Unpacking x11-common (1:7.7+19ubuntu14) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxss1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../22-libxss1_1%3a1.2.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxss1:amd64 (1:1.2.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtk8.6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../23-libtk8.6_8.6.10-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtk8.6:amd64 (8.6.10-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tk8.6-blt2.5.
Preparing to unpack .../24-tk8.6-blt2.5_2.5.3+dfsg-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tk8.6-blt2.5 (2.5.3+dfsg-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package blt.
Preparing to unpack .../25-blt_2.5.3+dfsg-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking blt (2.5.3+dfsg-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pip-whl.
Preparing to unpack .../26-python-pip-whl_20.0.2-5ubuntu1.10_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-pip-whl (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-lib2to3.
Preparing to unpack .../27-python3-lib2to3_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-lib2to3 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-distutils.
Preparing to unpack .../28-python3-distutils_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-distutils (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-setuptools.
Preparing to unpack .../29-python3-setuptools_45.2.0-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-setuptools (45.2.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-wheel.
Preparing to unpack .../30-python3-wheel_0.34.2-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-wheel (0.34.2-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-pip.
Preparing to unpack .../31-python3-pip_20.0.2-5ubuntu1.10_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pip (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-tk:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../32-python3-tk_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-tk:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up libxau6:amd64 (1:1.0.9-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.31.1-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up x11-common (1:7.7+19ubuntu14) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Setting up tzdata (2024a-0ubuntu0.20.04) ...

Current default time zone: 'Etc/UTC'
Local time is now:      Sun May 12 22:25:53 UTC 2024.
Universal Time is now:  Sun May 12 22:25:53 UTC 2024.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

Setting up libx11-data (2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up libpng16-16:amd64 (1.6.37-2) ...
Setting up libtcl8.6:amd64 (8.6.10+dfsg-1) ...
Setting up fonts-dejavu-core (2.37-1) ...
Setting up ucf (3.0038+nmu1) ...
Setting up libmpdec2:amd64 (2.4.2-3) ...
Setting up openssl (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.22) ...
Setting up libbsd0:amd64 (0.10.0-1) ...
Setting up readline-common (8.0-4) ...
Setting up libxdmcp6:amd64 (1:1.1.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libxcb1:amd64 (1.14-2) ...
Setting up fontconfig-config (2.13.1-2ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libreadline8:amd64 (8.0-4) ...
Setting up ca-certificates (20230311ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
137 added, 0 removed; done.
Setting up libfreetype6:amd64 (2.10.1-2ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up python-pip-whl (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.10) ...
Setting up libfontconfig1:amd64 (2.13.1-2ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9) ...
Setting up python3.8 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9) ...
Setting up libpython3-stdlib:amd64 (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libxrender1:amd64 (1:0.9.10-1) ...
Setting up libxext6:amd64 (2:1.3.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3 (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up python3-wheel (0.34.2-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libxss1:amd64 (1:1.2.3-1) ...
Setting up python3-lib2to3 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up python3-pkg-resources (45.2.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up python3-distutils (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up libxft2:amd64 (2.3.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-setuptools (45.2.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libtk8.6:amd64 (8.6.10-1) ...
Setting up python3-pip (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.10) ...
Setting up tk8.6-blt2.5 (2.5.3+dfsg-4) ...
Setting up blt (2.5.3+dfsg-4) ...
Setting up python3-tk:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20230311ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
+ pip3 install -q --no-cache-dir langchain faiss-cpu torch sentence_transformers
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

FATAL:   While performing build: while running engine: exit status 1

and the build is instantiated with sudo singularity build faiss_env.sif faiss_index_env.def
What I tried so far:

Tried enlarging the /tmp on my machine. Expected to see it not crash, but even though more memory was used (5GB out of 20GB) the build was still failing with the same error and the RAM usage was still crazy
Tried specifying the TMPDIR variable when using pip install ... to a fresh new directory inside the image but same problem occured
Tried using the --no-cache-dir option with pip install ... still no luck

If anyone could give me a helping hand it would be very much appreciated.

The problem was in the policy of Fedora 39 which mounts the /tmp folder in RAM. Disabling it fixed the issue.
Disable it only after reading and understanding what you are doing please.
To do so run the following:
systemctl mask tmp.mount

and then reboot.
See the github issue that I opened and the fedora page for reference.
